# how to lock access to django redis cache

Tags: django, python-3.x, caching, redis

I have concurrent access to a key in `django-redis-cache` by multiple gunicorn clients. How can I lock accessing to key so only one client can access `key` at each time?

Comment: simple way is to release your solution for `pop` the key and after processing put it back to redis, or add flag.

Comment: isn't it possible two client pop the key at the same time? and both get the same value?

Comment: someone will be first, and after pop for the second the key will not exists.

Comment: @BearBrown Thanks. it worked.

Answer (score -7, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, easy way is to define a key in redis cache and try to delete cache before accessing desired key.

```
while cache.delete('tmp_key') == 0:
    continue
# do something with your desired key
cache.set('tmp_key', 'unlocked', timeout=None)
```

Comment: This is not thread safe lock

Answer (score 4):

Django redis offers a [locking mechanism](https://niwinz.github.io/django-redis/latest/) you can use without running into a race condition. My *settings.py* file uses the same *CACHES* settings as specified by the documentation linked to above.

The following code shows the lock in the console:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'filestorage.settings')
from django.core.cache import caches
caches['default']
<django_redis.cache.RedisCache object at 0x7fbc817e03c8>
caches['default'].lock('la')
<redis.lock.LuaLock object at 0x7fbc80e772e8>
```

The lock can be used in a manner similar to [Python's threading.Lock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Lock):

```
l = caches['default'].lock('la')
l
<redis.lock.LuaLock object at 0x7fbc80e77320>
l.acquire()
True
l.release()
```